# Trim extension of files in an array with an efficient way

Tags: linux, bash

displays files in module folders without extension as well as adding them into an array.

```
function toolbox {
  array=(`ls "$1" | xargs`)
  len=${#array[array{@]}
  for (( i=0; i<$len; i++ ))
  do
    echo "`basename ${array[$1]} .ssh`"
  done
}
```

this will produce the desire result but I have to use the for loop.

```
toolbox "module"
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: `toolbox { for f in "$1"/*.ssh ; do [ -f "$f" ] && echo $(basename "$f" .ssh); done ; }` ?

Comment: @cas basename is 38K, and nobody specified "regular" files; but bash has special parameter expansion for suffixes (and prefixes).

Answer (score 3):

The `${var#word}` and `${var%word}` expansions work on arrays too:

```
arr=(/dir/dir1/foo.ssh /dir/dir2/bar.ssh )
arr2=("${arr[@]##*/}") 
arr2=("${arr2[@]%.ssh}") 
printf "%s\n" "${arr2[@]}"
```

prints `foo` and `bar`.

Then, that command substitution of `ls | xargs` will break with filenames containing spaces (even without `xargs`) or quotes (because of `xargs`).

You can, actually, expand a glob from just a variable, just *don't* quote it. Like so:

```
array=( $1 )
```

(Though `IFS` still matters, so patterns with whitespace would break, unless set it to the empty string first.)

Though if you're just looking for files with names ending in `.ssh`, you could just pass a directory as the argument and glob for `*.ssh` in the script:

```
array=( "$1"/*.ssh )
```

Answer (score 0):

script: (removes .ssh suffix and adds -SSH to each element)

```
array=(abc.ssh xyz.ssh ssh  "q r.ssh s.ssh" "mmm.ssh^Mnnn.ssh")

for e in "${array[@]}"
do
   echo ${e%.ssh}"-SSH"
done
```

output:

```
abc-SSH
xyz-SSH
ssh-SSH
q r.ssh s-SSH
nnn-SSH
```

With `"${array[*]}"`:

`nnn-SSH xyz.ssh ssh q r.ssh s.ssh mmm.ssh`

With  `${array[*]}`:

```
abc-SSH
xyz-SSH
ssh-SSH
q-SSH
r-SSH
s-SSH
nnn-SSH
```

The missing "mmm" is no wonder:

```
$  printf "a^Mb"
b$  echo "a^Mb"
b
$
```